# Meaning of "some" in "some <n> years"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-meaning

In the Wikipedia article "[Death of Azaria Chamberlain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Azaria_Chamberlain)" it reads:

> In 2012, **some** 32 years after Azaria's death, the Chamberlains' version of events was officially confirmed by a coroner.

What does the "some" mean here?

What is the difference to "In 2012, <s>some</s> 32 years after Azaria's death, […]"?

Comment: It's just another way of saying *about, approximately, around, not quite, almost*, etc. Sometimes you'll here *some 32 odd years ago* or *some 32 or so odd years ago*, but those are informal or colloquial to my ear. It's another way of saying *not exactly*.

Comment: @JohnQPublic: If you replace **some** in that sentence with *any* of the words *about, approximately, around, not quite, almost*, you change the meaning of the sentence by making the listener less confident in the accuracy of the number "32" and changing the focus of the sentence to emphasizing that "**the events were officially confirmed** 32 years after her death" from "the events were officially confirmed **32 years after her death**". Contrast with if you used the word "literally" in the colloquial usage as a meaningless intensifier, where the sentence then reads exactly the same.

Comment: @Matt While they're not all completely synonymous, **to me**, *some 32 years ago* means *not exactly*, *approximately*, or *just under/over*. When I encounter that phrase, I assume that the speaker intended to say *I haven't counted*, *very close*, *nearly/almost/just over*, *not exact to the date*, or, much less formally, *don't quote me on that figure*.

Comment: @JohnQPublic: In *some* cases, *some* means *approximately*. But not in this case (see my answer). Here it's just an intensifier, as you can see by the fact that the semantic meaning of the sentence shifts significantly if you replace "some" with a word that means "approximately", but very little if you change it to a different intensifier.

Comment: @Matt Point taken; now that you mention it, it could be read as an intensifier. That's poor diction for an encyclopedia though. I've actually never heard someone use it that way, but it does make sense sematically. Apparently I misread your answer the first time around.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, *some* is being used as a generic intensifier rather than to mean "approximately". It is used to express the surprise and incredulity by the author that it took a full 32 years for a coroner to officially record the Chamberlain's set of events leading up to the death after Azaria died - a time period quite dramatically longer than one would normally expect.

The sentence therefore is semantically equivalent to the following:

> In 2012, 32 years after Azaria's death(!), the Chamberlains' version of events was officially confirmed by a coroner.

Comment: It becomes clear to me now. At first I doubted that why the author chose the word *some* and yet wrote 32 years, not some 30 years. (I thought that maybe he didn't know exact number of months. Silly me.) Thanks Matt.

Comment: The sentence is *not* semantically equivalent to your version.  The wikipedia says *about* 32 years but your version says *fully* 32 years, which is false.  (17 August 1980 to 12 June 2012 is less than 32 full years.)

Comment: @jwpat7: It was "**fully** three percent lower" has the same semantic as "it was **some** three percent lower". Both are used exclusively as intensifiers and neither mean **approximately** - they both mean that "it was surprisingly/even/literally/astonishingly/most certainly three percent lower". Contrast with "It was some three percent lower **or so**", which means "It was approximately/circa/close to/near three percent lower".

Comment: It's interesting how much disagreement there is on this answer.  I wonder if some speakers only have the approximator *some*, while others have the "considerable quantity" *some* as well.

Comment: @snailboat: Perhaps the controversy is over my claim that "*fully*" can be just an intensifier (indeed, many words can be used "just" as an intensifier without intending their "real" meaning, e.g. "literally", "entirely", "fully", "completely", "totally"). I stand by that assertion - at least in the colloquial usage of it - but it's not what this question was about, so I've altered my answer to avoid using it.

Answer (score 2):

"`In 2012, 32 years after...`" would guarantee accuracy (*of 32 years*)
while
"`In 2012, some 32 years after...`" is to indicate to the reader that this fact is a close approximation. It doesn't guarantee the fact that *exactly* after 32 years, the said event had occurred.

Comment: I see, so it’s similar to "about" and "circa"? Would it be appropriate to use "some" even when the difference might be several years? Or do you only use "some" when the difference might be several months at max.?

Comment: @unor : yes. also, i think the usage of `some` is open for debate. you could say `some 1000 years later` and skew the figure by a few decades to a century while `some 15 minutes later` would mean around 15 minutes +/- a few minutes.

Comment: That's often what “some X years” means, but not in this case. Here, [it's an intensifier](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13812).

Comment: @Gilles : hm... noted but then which would you choose as a more accurate `intensifier`? -- `In 2012, some 32 years after...` or `In 2012, almost 32 years after...`.

Comment: I don't see how *almost* can be an intensifier. It would indicate that the actual time is less than 32 years, but not much less (a couple of months at most).

Comment: @Gilles : hm... i see.

Comment: Although "some" *can* be used to mean *approximately*, it would normally have to be paired with *or so* to make it more obviously the case that this is the intended meaning. For example "In 2012 - **some** sixty years **or so** after the war - we found an unexploded ordinance at the school."

Comment: @Matt : mmhmm... ok :)

Comment: Matt, your suggestion that pairing of *or so* with *some* is common does not reflect my experience.  Perhaps you could quote some evidence if you think it is common.

Comment: @jwpat7: It's not hard to find many examples online, such as this one [1](https://healthunlocked.com/psp/posts/909916/what-happens-to-all-of-you-that-was-enroled-in-davunetide-study-when-it-stopped), [2](http://www.gradyleach.com/grandmaster-xuan-kong/), [3](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Half-Elf,_Variant_(4e_Racial_Trait_Variant)), [4](http://www.gurdjiefflegacy.org/40articles/adida1.htm) etc - although even in these cases, "some" is a direct intensifier without approximation; the approximate nature of the number comes from "or so".

Comment: It's easy to find examples, but it's not particularly common to combine the two.  Usually *some* as an approximator isn't followed by *or so*.  Looking through 100 random results for `some thirty` in COCA, I see zero occurrences of *or so*.  (It would be quite a stretch to claim that none of these 100 results use *some* as an approximator.)

Comment: @snailboat: Sure. *Some* can *absolutely* be used as an approximator without *or so*, e.g. "It was some four hundred years ago that ..." or "The police said some four hundred protesters turned up for the event". But in this case, given that the number is already as accurate as any normal English speaker would give without sounding ridiculous (nobody would say "31.82 years later" or "31 years, 9 months and 26 days later"), *some* is here clearly *not* being used to mean approximate. It's a throw-away word designed only for emphasis with no semantic meaning in the sentence; i.e. an intensifier.

Comment: @snailboat: My point was that if the author had wanted to use *some* to mean *approximately*, s/he would have had to pair it with + "or so", or something similar in order to make the *some* have semantic - rather than merely emphatic meaning.

Comment: @Matt Yes, the approximator is generally used with round numbers, as in your examples, or with some other indicator that the number is approximate, such as a pair of successive numerals joined by OR ("some twelve or thirteen years later").